# kubectl run local docker image- ImagePullBackOff status

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

i build the docker image on my local machine and trying to pull docker image using kubectl. but its not starting the docker container.

images starts with docker command.

```
REPOSITORY                                            TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
tomcat9                                               latest              8b228ac6f19f        About an hour ago   111 MB
```

It stats with ImagePullBackOff   massage.

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                             READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
tomcat9-511437148-sgkwp          0/1       ImagePullBackOff   0          9m
```

How can I make kubectl to run this docker image?

Thanks

Comment: How are you trying to start the pod? Is there a `Deployment` or what is the command you are using? Where is your cluster hosted? Does your cluster have network access to your local repository?

Comment: @OswinNoetzelmann I used this command to start:  kubectl run tomcat9 --image tomcat9
trying this in minikube, my pods was running already. images and minikube runs on same machine.

Answer (score 13):

I see from your comments bellow you are using Minikube locally.

Minikube runs inside a virtual machine, the Docker running inside Minikube and the Docker running on you machine are two separate instances so will not have access to the same images, you can however link the Docker inside Minikube to your local Docker using `eval $(minikube docker-env)`, you can read more [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube#reusing-the-docker-daemon).

Also, you can get more information about why the `ImagePullBackOff` has happened by running `kubectl describe pods tomcat9-511437148-sgkwp`.

Comment: I tried with yaml file its working now. thanks for the comment.

Answer (score -2):

I used this yaml file, now image is deployed on the cluster.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tomcat9
  labels:
    app: tomcat9
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tomcat9
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: tomcat9:latest
        name: tomcat9
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
         - name: http
           containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: tomcat9
  labels:
    app: tomcat9
spec:
  ports:
  - nodePort: 30080
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080    
  selector:
    app: tomcat9
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: NodePort
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```