# kubectl run from local docker image?

Tags: macos, docker, kubernetes

How to refer to the local image that exists?

```
kubectl run u --rm -i --tty --image my_local_image -- bash
```

Results in `ImagePullBackOff` and `kubectl` is obviously trying to pull from a remote repository instead of local register.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43462384/kubectl-run-local-docker-image-imagepullbackoff-status) is unhelpful, and the follow up refers to minikube and kubernetes.

Some event logs

```
Events:
  Type     Reason                 Age               From                         Message
  ----     ------                 ----              ----                         -------
  Normal   Scheduled              1m                default-scheduler            Successfully assigned u-6988b9c446-zcp99 to docker-for-desktop
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  1m                kubelet, docker-for-desktop  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-q2qm7"
  Normal   SandboxChanged         1m                kubelet, docker-for-desktop  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Normal   Pulling                23s (x3 over 1m)  kubelet, docker-for-desktop  pulling image "centos_postgres"
  Warning  Failed                 22s (x3 over 1m)  kubelet, docker-for-desktop  Failed to pull image "centos_postgres": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for centos_postgres, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
  Warning  Failed                 22s (x3 over 1m)  kubelet, docker-for-desktop  Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff                9s (x5 over 1m)   kubelet, docker-for-desktop  Back-off pulling image "centos_postgres"
  Warning  Failed                 9s (x5 over 1m)   kubelet, docker-for-desktop  Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Kubernetes Pods have an `imagePullPolicy` field. If you set that to `Never`, it will never try to pull an image, and it's up to you to ensure that the docker daemon which the kubelet is using contains that image. The default policy is `IfNotPresent`, which should work the same as `Never` if an image is already present in the docker daemon. Double check that your docker daemon actually contains what you think it contains, and make sure your `imagePullPolicy` is set to one of the two that I mentioned.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: my-image
      image: local-image-name
      imagePullPolicy: Never
```